# Invalid changelist number 'default <other-user>@<workspace>'

Tags: perforce

Recently perforce started complaining with:

> Invalid changelist number 'default <other-user>@<workspace>'

when a user, other than `<other-user>`, switches to that `<workspace>`, unshelves stuff into that `<workspace>` etc.

Acknowledging the error one may proceed, but it would be nice to know how to get rid of this warning.

Comment: Don't yada-yada over actual steps.  What are some exact commands (with the full command lines) that exhibit this problem?

Comment: This is all from p4v and I (and others that report that to me) didn't really look at the log window to see the actual commands.  It happens on submit, sync, switch to another workspace, thus whatever command or command sequence p4v issues for those.

Comment: Sometimes it's too hard to get the users to describe the exact actions they took in P4V, so you can also contact your Perforce server administrator and ask him/her to examine the Perforce server logs, which can be configured to record the exact requests that P4V makes of the server, together with the errors (if any) that result.

Comment: Yup, but not that easy when your P4 server has over 1000 users and the admin is 12 time zones away.  I'll need to get to those two machines where this happens and check it out myself, but as this is only an annoyance it is low on my queue (not my job anyway). I was just trying google/p4-forums/stackoverflow for the easy answer :-)

Comment: My money would be on a malfunctioning trigger, personally.

Comment: We tie one workspace to a given machine, where a common user is always logged on to, then run p4 as ourselves using our domain account.  I just logged on and have an empty default pending changelist, but it has the resolve icon on it!  Someone does have files checked on the default changelist, but under their logon.  I think maybe the latest p4 gets confused by this scenario, when earlier versions never complained.